# Can I somehow listen on the URL user is typing with Firefox addon SDK?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there a way with Firefox Add-on SDK to get the URL while user is typing it in the location field?

Comment: I listen and respond to user typing in url bar here to allow shortcuts to new tab tiles: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nthotkey/?src=search it uses the `addEventListener` on `keyup` as @nmaier mentioned below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. Yes it is possible, but not within the SDK standard API.

1. You need to enumerate top-level browser windows (aka. type `navigator:browser`, `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul`). [`window/utils::windows()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/window_utils#windows%28%29) may help here, but it has the drawback that it will not notify you about new windows. However, you can use [`require("chrome")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Chrome_Authority) and [`nsIWindowWatcher.registerNotification`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWindowWatcher) for that.
2. Once you got to the browser windows, it is a matter of adding the usual key event listeners using the usual `addEventListener` DOM API. The DOM element in `browser.xul` you're looking for is `#urlbar`.
3. Since SDK add-ons are restartless, and you're leaving the *managed* land, using the low-level APIs, you need to clean up after yourself on unload, e.g. remove any event listeners or observers again and restore anything you touched.

Comment: @o.O this is how I enuemrate top level browser windows and add to it from bootstrap addons, just add into the loadIntoWindow and unloadFromWindow functions: [GitHubGIST :: _ff-addon-snippet-BootstrapBoiler_WindowListener.js](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/1c7ab2c49c7640ff84db)